# R scale circle with unequal axis

Tags: r, math, plot, drawing

I want to draw a circle on a cartesian coordinate system, where the interval of the `x-axis` is unequal to the interval of the `y-axis`.

For example see the image attached, where `x` is in the interval `[0 ... 40]` and `y` is in the interval `[90 ... 107]`.

[image: Brown Motion with circle]

Below see the fully functional code needed to create the image. Keep in mind, that Brownian Motion is random each time, giving another `y-axis` interval and therefore a different distorted circle.

```
library(sde)

#  brown motion
brown.motion <- BM(x=100, t0=0, T=40, N=100) # get brownian motion
# plot bronwian motion
plot(brown.motion, main='Brownian Motion with circle', ylab='Value', xlab='Time')

#  circle
# define the points
x1 <- 21
x2 <- 26
y1 <- max(brown.motion) - (max(brown.motion) - min(brown.motion)) / 2
y2 <- max(brown.motion) - (max(brown.motion) - min(brown.motion)) / 3

# calculate the line
m <- (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
xx <- seq(x1, x2, by=0.02)
yy <- m * xx + (y1 - m * x1)

# plot the line
lines(xx, yy)

# plot the center
points(xx[round(length(xx) / 2)], yy[round(length(yy) / 2)])

# calculate the length
eukl.norm.vec <- function(x) sqrt(sum(x^2)) # function euclidean norm
vec1 <- c(x1, y1)
vec2 <- c(x2, y2)
length <- eukl.norm.vec(vec2 - vec1)

# calculate radius for circle
real.radius <- length / 2

# calculate circle
circle.degree <- seq(0, 2*pi, by=0.01)
circle.x <- real.radius * cos(circle.degree) + x1 + real.radius
circle.y <- real.radius * sin(circle.degree) + y1 + real.radius

# plot circle
lines(circle.x, circle.y)
```

How can I draw the circle around the center (single dot) such that the circle touches the line on both ends (the lines are fully in the circle)?

I thought about multiplication with a factor, but could not find a suitable one so far.

Comment: Try `plot(brown.motion, main='Brownian Motion with circle', ylab='Value', xlab='Time', asp = 1)`

Comment: That's true, this does solve the "unequal axis", but then there is a lot of "unused" area and also the circle is not drawn right, there must be a logic mistake in my code.

Comment: My bad, I was calculating the circles the wrong way. I had to delete the part behind `cricle.x <- real.radius * cos(circle.degree)` and add `(max(x1, x2) + min(x1, x2)) / 2` instead. For the `y`-part analogously. Then I can easily scale the `y`-part with an arbitrary factor.